# How to change the Font in your legend to a windows font

Tags: r, fonts, gplots

How can I change the Font and the size in R. I want it Times New Roman is it possible. Where should I put the command this the script that I've been trying to change the font

Comment: are you using ggplot2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to changing the font in a plot's legend and labels.  Then here is a possible solution using ggplot2.  A full list of fonts can be found [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Fonts/).

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(a=runif(100), 
                 b=runif(100),
                 c=sample(c("Class A","Class B"), 100, T))

ggplot(df, aes(x=a,y=b,colour=c)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme(text=element_text(family="Times"))
```